# Tree-style-tab that hierarchically orders tabs by domain

Tags: firefox

The [Tree style tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) Firefox add-on creates a sidebar where tabs are shown in a tree, typically based on how they have opened.  A [feature request to order them by domain](https://github.com/piroor/treestyletab/issues/1660) was rejected with the commentary that it should be done by an add-on.  Does such an add-on (either to Tree Style Tab, or directly to Firefox) exist?  Ideally, the behaviour I'm looking for is:

```
+ stackexchange.com
  - https://stackexchange.com/filters/63625/favo
  - https://stackexchange.com/
  + earthscience.stackexchange.com
    - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/239/impossible-or-improbable-hurricane-crossing-the-equator
+ docs.dask.org
  - https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv
```

There is some of that in [Sidebar+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sidebar_plus/), although without the hierarchical bit; `earthscience.stackexange.com` is listed completely separately from `stackexchange.com`.  In general, I find Tree Style Tab prettier, and it shows how many tabs are collapsed away.

Is there any such add-on?  In case it matters, I'm using Firefox 68.2.0esr.